# regular language?

Tags: automata, regular-language

I need help proving whether this language is regular or not.

$$L = \big\{ w \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*, n_a(w)\text{ is even}, n_b(w)\text{ is even}\big\}$$

That is, the number of $a$'s is even and the number of $b$'s in $w$ is even.

I'm not sure whether I can draw a dfa for this. Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 4 states. One where $n_a(w)$ even and $n_b(w)$ even, one where $n_a(w)$ even and $n_b(w)$ odd, one where $n_a(w)$ odd and $n_b(w)$ even, and one where $n_a(w)$ odd and $n_b(w)$ even.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try making a DFA with four states, $s_{00},s_{01},s_{10}$, and $s_{11}$. Design it so that when it has read a word with $m$ $a$’s and $n$ $b$’s, it’s in state $s_{m\bmod 2,n\bmod 2}$. (Here $n\bmod 2$ is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $2$, so it’s $0$ if $n$ is even and $1$ if $n$ is odd.)

**Added:** Here’s your DFA, from the comments, with $q_0$ starred as initial state and underlined as acceptor state. As you can see, each $a$ input moves the automaton horizontally, and each $b$ input moves it vertically, so the states in the top row correspond to an even number of $b$’s, and the states in the lefthand column to an even number of $a$’s.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\underline{q_0^*}&\overset{a}\longleftrightarrow&q_1\\
b\updownarrow&&\updownarrow b\\
q_2&\underset{a}\longleftrightarrow&q_3
\end{array}$$

Comment: Hi just wondering if you could check my answer.
my dfa is the following:
       a      b
q0     q1     q2 
q1     q0     q3
q2     q3     q0
q3     q2     q1

Comment: @TonsOfDamage: I’m interpreting that to mean that there are $a$-transitions from $q_0$ to $q_1$, $q_1$ to $q_0$, $q_2$ to $q_3$, and $q_3$ to $q_2$, and $b$-transitions from $q_0$ to $q_2$, $q_1$ to $q_3$, $q_2$ to $q_0$, and $q_3$ to $q_1$. If $q_0$ is both your initial state and your only acceptor state, that DFA works fine.

Comment: Yes, you interpreted that right. However, I made my initial state q0 and my final/acceptor state q1. Could you tell me if this works? or if q0 should be my initial and accepting state?

Comment: @TonsOfDamage: $q_0$ should also be your acceptor state. If you start in $q_0$, after an even number of $a$’s you’ll be in $q_0$ or $q_2$, and after an even number of $b$’s you’ll be in $q_0$ or $q_1$; you want both, so you want to be in $q_0$. If you’re in $q_1$, you’ve read an odd number of $a$’s and an even number of $b$’s.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @TonsOfDamage: You’re welcome. Now that you’ve got it, I’ve added your DFA to the answer to make it absolutely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a regular expression would work as well. The key point is to observe, that you could split any word of $L$ into chunks $ba^k$ and some simple leftovers.
The only thing we need to fix is that the number of $b$s and $a$s has to be even, but then $ba^*ba^*$ would do the job. One could derive from this a single expression, however, it is much easier to split it in two and intersect (regular languages are closed for intersection).

\begin{align}
L_a &= b^*(ab^*ab^*)^*, \text{ the language of even $a$s}\\
L_b &= a^*(ba^*ba^*)^*, \text{ the language of even $b$s}\\
L &= L_a \cap L_b.
\end{align}

I hope it helps ;-)